# Android AQuery for Image Loading

Tags: android, image, aquery

Currently i m using Android AQuery and displaying it and its working fine.
but i m having an issue that if image that is returned from Web server is not of same size as that of image container then  it does not fit to the container. I have used the following piece of code of Aqery

```
mAquery.id(Thmbnail).auth(handle).image(DetailData.get(Position).getImageURL(),true,true,0,0,null,0,mAquery.RATIO_PRESERVE);
```

If I use

```
mAquery.RATIO_PRESERV
```

then images become of weird size and if i use ration then it results crop image 
does any one here have any idea about this that it won`t crop the image and use the container size of image view 
Thank you in advance for help

Comment: Does the solution have to involve aQuery? The [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) has a method to fit images, and has a lot of nice caching features.

Comment: yes soultion has to be work around with aQuery

Comment: As AQery author wrote to you before the problem is with ImageView properties not AQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to stretch the image?

In that case just use fitXY scale type in the xml layout of ImageView and use ratio of 0.

Comment: The question is how to preserve aspect ratio and the image view not cropping the image. With your solution, as you say the image will stretch and it doesn't preserve the aspect ratio. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

This should solve your problem:

```
AQuery.FADE_IN

mAquery.id(Thmbnail).auth(handle).image(DetailData.get(Position).getImageURL(),true,true,0,0,null,mAquery.RATIO_PRESERVE, AQuery.FADE_IN);
```